# Javascript: Removing empty elements from a large array by index pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I would like to reduce the size of a javascript array by removing empty nodes at regular intervals (most likely every even or odd node). Is there a simple and efficient way of doing this using built-in javascript or d3.js methods?

**Background**

For a data-driven, in-browser application, I have an array with indexing representing units on a horizontal time scale.

Initial timescale intervals are an algorithmic best guess, but often, far from all index points have data associated with them. In fact, on the basis of minimum time intervals found, I can often identify a regular **pattern** of unused elements which can be removed entirely and without impacting any data.

Mapping a timescale to real data is easy enough using d3 selections (empty elements are ignored), but given the size of these arrays and the fact that they are passed around a bit, early removal seems to make sense. Where data *does* exist, it is very large (a tree), so deletions are perhaps best made in-situ rather than through creation of a new array.

From the array documentation (native and d3.js) I see a couple of possible approaches, but am a little wary both of compatability issues and possible side effects. Perhaps surprisingly, I also found no examples related to array **index** pattern matching.

To sum up:

1. the nodes to be deleted follow a pattern (every 2nd node etc)
2. these nodes are guaranteed empty.
3. no further dependencies (jQuery etc) thanks.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it 'by hand' or use the filter function.

The filter function is faster... to write :

```
function isEmptyNode(x, i ) { return ( i & 1 ) } ;   // to keep odd nodes

var myNewArray = myOldArray.filter(isEmptyNode) ;
```

... but the good old for loop (in-place) is way way way faster :

```
var dst=0;
for (var i=0, len=myArray.length; i<len ; i++ ) { if (i & 1) myArray[dst++]=myArray[i] }
myArray.length = dst;
```

You can easily change the  `if (i & 1)` by a `if (myTestFunction(i))` to have a more generic filtering.

For the performances, yo can check here that it's more than 100 times faster with a for loop : 
http://jsperf.com/filter-odd-items-in-array/2